# Fan for Ryzen 2600

Tags: processor, cooling

I have a `Ryzen 2600` and I won't OC. I find the default cooler too noisy (I don't have heating problems, max temp after a stress test was 67ºC).

My priority is reducing noise. I have checked some candidates and I've seen their max dB, but most of the time I won't have my CPU at 100%.

I have the following candidates: `Thermalright Le Grand Macho RT`, `Thermalright ARO-M14G`, `Noctua NH-U12S SE-AM4` and `Be Quiet! Dark Rock 4`. The prices are approximately the same.

Which one do you recommend me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I bought Be Quiet! Dark Rock 4. I can't compare with the other ones but it is what I was looking for. I barely hear it.